# passing 'this' on onClick event function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which look like this:

```
<table bordered='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td><td><a href="#" onclick="delete(this);">x</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ball</td><td><a href="#" onclick="delete(this);">x</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
function delete(clickedOne) {
    alert(clickedOne);
   clickedOne.parent().parent().remove();     
}
</script>
```

Now what I want to do is delete the "tr" which 'x' has been clicked. For this I need to let my delete function to know which 'x' has been clicked. But 'this' as a parameter seems like not working.

Note: I can't put **id** in my table elements.

Comment: You are using jquery. Why dont you use it consistently ?

Comment: Avoid inline JavaScript. Also, don't name your function `delete`.

Comment: In addition to the valid comments above, `clickedOne` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Also, `delete` isn't a great function name as it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: In POJS parents are accessed as properties (much faster than jQuery's *parent* method): `var tr = clickedOne.parentNode.parentNode; tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:

`delete` is a reserved keyword. If you looked at your JavaScript console you would see an error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token delete

Call your function something else.

---

Second:

`clickedOne` is a DOM Node but `parent()` is a jQuery method.

You want `clickedOne.parentNode.parentNode` to reach the `tr` element (and then you want to call `removeChild` on the table row's parent element).

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use jquery, because the dom handling is easier and it's also the proper way to separate javascript from html

if you wanted to use jquery, a better way than using parent().parent() ist to get all parents and filter them.

```
$(function() {
  $(".myTable a").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

and change your html like this:

```
<table bordered='1' class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td><td><a href="#">x</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ball</td><td><a href="#">x</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

you can test it on the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SP2X9/

Answer (score 0):

you can just give class and onclick function

```
    <a href="#" class="delete_row">x</a>
    $(function() {
      $(".delete_row").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
    });
```